# Had B'nai Yisra'el not sent the spies, would they have had to fight against Amalek?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, army-military-war, amalek, meraglim-spies, parshat-devarim

Rashi on [Devarim 1:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=10) says that if it weren't for the sin with the spies, we would have never needed armaments.

[Bamidbar 14:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39995&st=&pgnum=103) tells us that Amalek lived in the valleys, and [Devarim 25:29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=316&hilite=) states that we must rid of the memory of Amalek, implying our own actions.

Judging from Rash"i's comments on Devarim 1:8, would there have been no mitzvah to rid Amalaek if we didn't have the sin of the spies? Would God have eradicated them for us?

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam ([Malachim U'Milchamos 1:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e501.htm#2)) says that the Mitzvah of destroying Amalek only applies once a King is appointed, and a King is only appointed after they have conquered the land.

So the need for armaments would not have been then, but rather only later.

Comment: OK. But, the main focus of my question is if Amalek would have already been driven out of the land prior to B'nai Yisra'el entering it?

Comment: @DanF, Amalek wasn't one of the seven nations that needed to be conquered to inhabit the land.

Comment: I know that. So, essentially, Rashi's comment in Devarim 1:5 refers only to the 7 nations? Difficult to understand that, b/c he says there would be no need for armaments - seems to mean "at all". It's different than saying, "You wouldn't need to fight so and so", which would be more specific.

Comment: @DanF, the context of Rashi is the land that they would inherit (referenced in verses 7 and 8 there). Rashi's point is that they would have inherited it straight up without conquest if not for ...

Answer (score 0):

I found this drasha on the  [Daf Yomi Notes for Megillah 16](http://dafnotes.com/english_dafyomi/megillah/Megillah_16.pdf):

> The Gemora relates that Achashverosh ordered Haman to get Mordechai,
>   dress him in the royal garments and lead him through the city on the
>   king’s horse proclaiming, “Thus shall be done for the man whom the
>   king wishes to honor.” Haman located Mordechai teaching his students
>   the laws of kemitzah (scooping the flour for the mincha offering).
>   Rashi states that this occurred on the sixteenth of Nissan, the day
>   the korban omer is offered in the Beis Hamikdosh.
>
> The Maharal explains the connection between the omer offering and the
>   story of Purim. The Omer offering reveals the miracles that are hidden
>   inside of nature. By bringing the first grain to the Beis Hamikdosh,
>   we are demonstrating that even the nature of the world is governed by
>   Hashem. This was the method used to overcome Haman. The miracles were
>   concealed from the human eye. The means to conquer Haman and Amalek is
>   by exposing the concealed miracles, thus confirming that all which
>   appears natural is controlled by Hashem.

In summary, based on Maharal's explanation, G-d could not have gotten rid of Amalek for us.

See the "Daily Mashal" near the end of the linked article for further explanation and other views on this. I could only excerpt a section!